# How to change HTTP context method to Curl for post action

Tags: php, ssl, curl, http-post

I am trying to get response from server using HTTP context:

```
$cparams = array(
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>true,
            "verify_peer_name"=>true,
        ),
        'http' => $request['httpOptions']
    );

$context = stream_context_create($cparams);
$fp = fopen($request['url'], 'rb', false, $context);
```

But it showing

> Error in exception handler: fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

This is the URL:

```
$url = EZPAY_SERVER . "/hps/webservice/ezpay/CreateSessionKey";
```

ie,

> https://psp.stg.transactium.com/hps/webservice/ezpay/CreateSessionKey?privateMerchantKey=********************

So i want to try it with Curl,

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$request['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch); 

    curl_close ($ch);
```

But now I'am getting this error.

> A public action method 'CreateSessionKey' was not found on controller
>   'Transactium.HostedPayment.Controllers.EZPayController'. Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/ezpay/library/EZPay.php on line 12

Comment: The second error is not related to curl, it is created from your application. Can you check if you have made some mistakes on your application?

Comment: @Ben I'am trying to intrgrate ezpay payment gateway.so initially a sesionkey is required as response from ezpay.there I'am getting this error.Ezpay controller is not in our application.So how can i check that?

Comment: you should check their manual which parameters are required to request their gateway.

Comment: that i have mentioned in the question. The first code using http context

Comment: related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Comment: yeah I'am following that.For this request, the only one  parameter to be sent is the merchant key and it is already included in the url.so i think no need to include  other parameters in the curl( as mentioned in the http context method($cparams)). I tried that also. but the same error.

Comment: can you update the post to include the updated code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161075/discussion-between-shalom-and-ben).